# the problem when running the node rviz

Tags: rviz, rosrun

[image: Rosanswers logo]

when I run the node "rviz" in the comamnd line like this:rosrun rviz rviz
It shows as below:

[ INFO] [1346789635.814828803]: rviz revision number 1.6.7
[ INFO] [1346789635.814946913]: ogre_tools revision number 1.6.2
[ INFO] [1346789635.814969418]: compiled against OGRE version 1.7.3 (Cthugha)
[ INFO] [1346789636.052944712]: Loading general config from [/home/sven/.rviz/config]
[ INFO] [1346789636.053087637]: Loading display config from [/home/sven/.rviz/display_config]
[ INFO] [1346789636.081075486]: RTT Preferred Mode is PBuffer.
The program 'rviz' received an X Window System error.
This probably reflects a bug in the program.
The error was 'BadDrawable (invalid Pixmap or Window parameter)'.
(Details: serial 21 error_code 9 request_code 55 minor_code 0)
(Note to programmers: normally, X errors are reported asynchronously;
that is, you will receive the error a while after causing it.
To debug your program, run it with the --sync command line
option to change this behavior. You can then get a meaningful
backtrace from your debugger if you break on the gdk_x_error() function.)

Is there problems with the node "rviz" or something wrong with my PC?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/42941/the-problem-when-running-the-node-rviz/) by [sven_007](https://answers.ros.org/users/1417/sven_007/) on ROS Answers with karma: 49 on 2012-09-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

http://ros.org/wiki/rviz/Troubleshooting

Hi, it's all written in the site! I use, before to run rviz, "export OGRE_RTT_MODE=Copy" and rviz runs!

---

Originally posted by [Yuri](https://answers.ros.org/users/2892/yuri/) with karma: 42 on 2012-09-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sven_007](https://answers.ros.org/users/1417/sven_007/) on 2012-10-30**:
Thank you very much!